# Oracle: Procedure/Cursor - UPDATE, SET

Tags: oracle

I have been working on a class assignment and for some reason the only one i can not solve is a procedure with a courser... can some one provide me guidance? 
So i need to take an email's domain and update it. EXAMPLE: boogers@us.now into boogers@gmail.com

RULES REQUIRE A CURSOR::

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_Q3
(P_Domain Varchar2)
AS
V_Old Varchar2(30);
V_New Varchar2(30);
EmailDomain Broker%ROWTYPE;
CURSOR DomainCursor IS SELECT Email_Address
                        FROM Broker
                        WHERE Email_Address = SUBSTR(Email_address,'@') -1;
BEGIN 
  OPEN DomainCursor;
    LOOP 
      FETCH DomainCursor INTO V_Old;
      EXIT WHEN DomainCursor%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(EmailDomain.Email_Address || ' , ' );
      UPDATE Broker
      SET Email_Address = V_New
      WHERE Email_Address = SUBSTR(Email_Address, '@' ) - 1;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE DomainCursor;
END PR_Q3;
/
SHOW ERROR;


EXEC('now.ca','gmail.com')
```

Comment: I've answered such a question recently; have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692823/replacing-email-domains/52699143#52699143

Comment: *"RULES REQUIRE A CURSOR"* - classic example of schoolwork assignment demanding a sub-optimal solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this ananymous block if not finding actual queries:

```
Declare
V_Old Varchar2(30);
V_New Varchar2(30);
name_wo_domain Varchar2(30);
cursor DomainCursor is select Email_Address from Broker;
v_domain Varchar2(30) :='gmail.com';

BEGIN 
FOR i in DomainCursor
LOOP
      select REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.Email_Address,'[^@]+',1,1) 
      into name_wo_domain
      from dual;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.Email_Address || ' , ' );
      UPDATE Broker
      SET Email_Address = name_wo_domain||'@'||v_domain
      WHERE Email_Address = i.Email_Address;
    END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END ;
```

Comment: Thank you,  i will try most of this. however, the gmail was an example i need to put the change into the EXEC